# IndentationError: expected an indented block dataset=list()

Tags: python, linear-regression

Getting this error while running the 2nd below code .Can anyone tell me how to fix it ?

```
File "<ipython-input-2-b17fa66ce8c6>", line 3
    dataset = list()
          ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block


def load_csv(filename):
dataset = list()
with open(filename, 'r') as file:
csv_reader = reader(file)
for row in csv_reader:
if not row:
continue
dataset.append(row)
return dataset
```

Comment: (1) Format your posts on StackOverflow with correct indentation.  (2) Format your Python code with correct indentation.  In each case, indent logical blocks with 4 spaces.  (2) should solve your problem, (1) will make your post better in line with this forum's posting guidelines.

Comment: If you don't know what indentation is: *"Indentation (typesetting), the placement of text farther to the right, or left, to separate it from surrounding text. Indent style, in programming a convention governing the indentation of blocks of code to convey the program's structure."* - from Wikipedia.

Comment: Side-note: When opening a file for use with the `csv` module, you need to pass `newline=''` as an argument to `open`; specific newline formats are important to CSV formats, and `open` should not be translating them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tabs and spaces are really important in Python. Your code should look like:

```
def load_csv(filename):
    dataset = list()
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        csv_reader = reader(file)
        for row in csv_reader:
            if not row:
                continue
            dataset.append(row)
    return dataset
```